# Server returned HTTP response code: 403 (System.setProperty won't work)

Tags: java, heroku, cloudflare

I'm trying to parse an online txt file to get a boolean in java.

I've done this before, and had the same issue, but I moved the website to a new host, and the old fix wont work anymore.

I use NameCheap > CloudFlare > Heroku > GitHub Pages (*.shaybox.com)
and
NameCheap > CloudFlare > 000webhost (dev.shaybox.com) (for ftp ability)

I've tried this on both hosting methods, and it gives the same error.
The file is accessable with my browser normally, but not in java.

Main.Class: http://pastebin.com/36pndkft
Error: http://pastebin.com/aUBtMyJP
(I don't know how to use the code section)

I don't have the code that turns it into a boolean in there, just the main part.

It's probably something with my CloudFlare settings, but I don't know where.

Comment: Don't link to code, paste your code here.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know if I should have or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be triggering Cloudflare security mechanisms by doing this. You can instruct Cloudflare to not to challenge a particular IP in the Firewall app.

The Cloudflare Knowledge Base contains detail on the [Cloudflare IP Firewall](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-How-do-I-control-access-to-my-site-); but as a high level overview:

1. Login to your CloudFlare account.
2. Go to the Firewall app.
3. Add an IP, IP Range, Autonomous System Number (ASN) or Country Code - alongside selecting the whitelist option.
4. Click `Add`.

[image: Cloudflare IP Firewall]

Comment: I'll try that and let you know if that fixes it, Thanks

Comment: That did fix it! Thanks.  
Would there be any way to disable that protection all together?  
Or whitelist every IP?  
I keep it on "Essentially Off"